# Let $R$ be the relation on $\mathbb Z^+ \times \mathbb Z^+$ such that $(a, b)R(c, d)$ if $gcd(a, b) = gcd(c, d)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I need to find out:

1. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.
   (I am not clear on definition of an equivalence relation)
2. What is the equivalence class of $(1,2)$?
3. Give an interpretation of the equivalence classes of $R$.

This as far as I could go, see below.

[image]

I am wondering if I got it right this time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation $\mathcal R$ is an equivalence relation if it's *reflexive*, *symmetic* and *transitive*.

The equivalence class $[(1,2)]=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z^+}\times \mathbb{Z^+}\ | \gcd(a,b)=1$} hence $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Notice that any relation $\mathcal R$ defined by *equality*:
$$x\mathcal R y\iff f(x)=f(y)$$
is arguably an equivalence relation.